# How to limit the installation of Android App only to the premium user.

Tags: android, google-play

Description : I have Tracking Application , I am posting it on Google Play . I have two version of App one is the free version and other one is for premium user.

In Free version any once can download my app from Google play..

For premium version: I will give license to App for the particular User who buys it..

Problem: I don't want my premium version app to be shared to other device. I want premium version app to be installed to that person who buys it and I am giving the domain to the premium user who can track his/her record from web page...

Can anybody tell me how to maintain this records so that i can restrict my premium version app  to be get installed from other device...

Some solution which i thought is : I will maintain an IMEI number along with license code when user install the app , I will block that license ..

Any other solution please suggest me...

Comment: ...and if the premium user's phone breaks and he has to get a new one with a new IMEI?

Comment: Yea it will be problem so what could be possible solution for this ??

Comment: The "normal" way to do it is to use [Google Play Licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/overview.html), which works as users expect it to work.

Comment: Okie i have read the article .. Can we restrict the user using DeviceLimiter concept ?

Comment: If you want to limit the number of devices the premium user can use the app on, yes, that is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't do this. This is inconsistent with user expectations.

Google Play allows you to release your application (or a version of it) for a fee. Google takes a transaction fee from this, and you receive the rest. In exchange, the user is able to install the application on any device their account is linked to.

Adding arbitrary restrictions like the ones you propose will frustrate users; I would strongly advise you to avoid it unless you have a very compelling reason to implement them.

Edit: as has been pointed out elsewhere in this thread, you can use `DeviceLimiter` from the licensing API. I would still advise against this for the other reasons above, but it is *possible*.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow anybody to install it but ask for login. In that way only registered users can use that application.

Give licence number for only whom purchased the application. Ask and validate the licence number during the first time login.